# (sqlite) How to share the same Primary Key across four tables

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I'm really new to setting relationships between tables.

I created 4 tables and they're in a one-on-one relationship, so I want to make these tables share the PK.

I'm using db browser for sqlite.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "share the PK"? You will need to create a respective column in each of the tables and insert the same value in each of the tables for the corresponding rows

Comment: You might also look at [Foreign Keys](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) to help ensure consistency.